# Mantaining dropdown.. Script is so long?

Tags: php

I've read that using session is one way to retain the values from PHP submit failure. The data is wiped out as soon as you send the form to the server so to get back the data, a session should be use. I have a dropdown that is a list of country. It contains more than 60-80 countries. I used the ternary condition to make the script shorter but it's still very long and tiresome.

It looks like this

```
<option value="Afghanistan" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["errors"]) && $_SESSION["country"] == "Afghanistan") ? "SELECTED" : ""; ?> >Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["errors"]) && $_SESSION["country"] == "Albania") ? "SELECTED" : ""; ?>>Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["errors"]) && $_SESSION["country"] == "Algeria") ? "SELECTED" : ""; ?>>Algeria</option>
```

As I continue this, I thought that there must be another way. Is this a good method? When I see php scripts that is very long, I tend to think that I'm not doing the right way. The list goes on up till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the list of countries in an array, and loop through it to generate the option tags, for instance:

```
<?php
// Assuming $countries is an array of country names
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $selected = (isset($_SESSION['errors']) && $_SESSION['country'] == $country)
        ? 'SELECTED' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$country\" $selected>$country</option>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: How and where would I put the variable selected?

Comment: Your code works. But I want to ask something. Why is it that the selected variable works even though it's not enclosed with quotations nor it doesn't have an semi-colon at the end, i'm pointing out the semi colon for the echo not for the tertary condition.

Comment: Whoops - I didn't actually *use* the `$selected` var in the <option> tag output.  Edited the answer to fix that.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean about the semi-colon - the line which assigns a value to $selected breaks across two lines, but shortened for clarity it's `$selected = (cond) ? 'SELECTED' : '';`

Comment: The whole thing is one statement, so there's one semi-colon at the end of the whole statement, as per the shortened example.

Comment: I have last question.. What if I'm using a for loop?
for ($i=0; $i<=30; $i++)
{
$selected = (isset($_SESSION["errors"]) && $_SESSION["day"] == $day) ? "SELECTED" : "";
$day = 1 + $i;
echo "<option value=\"$day\" $selected>$day</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>";

I tried to select the day but it's always incremented by 1.

Comment: Er, what?  Firstly, we're talking days, so start with 1 and end with 31, rather than starting at zero and adding one - `for ($day=1; $day <= 31; $day++) { ... }` - then use $day inside the loop happily.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned a lot from your answers! Thanks!